# How to sorted the list of model instance by number of an other related model in django REST?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have 2 models is `Product` and `Watch`. A `Product` may have multiple `Wacht`.

**When I call the API to get the list of products. I want to provide a feature for ordering the products by a number of watches that each product has like below.**

> domainname/products/?ordering=numberOfWatch

Here is my model

```
class Product(models.Model):
    # product model fields
```

and `Wacht` model

```
class Watch(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(
        Product,
        related_name='watches',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    # other fields
```

and the `ProductList` View

```
class ProductList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, IsAdmin,)
    name = 'product-list'
    filter_fields = ('category', 'brand', 'seller')
    search_fields = ('name',)
    ordering_fields = ('-updated_at', 'price', 'discount_rate', 'discount')
    ordering = ('-updated_at',)
```

I'm thinking of add `watch_count` field in `Product` model and ordering for that field. But is that a good way to get what I need?

Answer (score 0):

General way:

```
from django.db.models import Count

Product.objects.all().annotate(watch_count=Count("watches")).order_by("-watches")
```

the direction of the ordering can be changed by removing `-` from `order_by`

In order to implement this in DRF (with Django-Filter), you have to use custom ordering filter. Simple example:

```
class CustomOrderingFilter(filters.OrderingFilter):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.extra['choices'] += [
            ('watch_count', 'Watch count low to high'),
            ('-watch_count', 'Watch count high to low'),
        ]

    def filter(self, qs, value):

        if value and any(v in ['watch_count', '-watch_count'] for v in value):
            qs = Product.objects.all().annotate(watch_count=Count("watches"))
            if 'watch_count' in value:
                qs = qs.order_by("watches")
            elif '-watch_count' in value:
                qs = qs.order_by("-watches")

            return qs

        return super().filter(qs, value)


ordering = CustomOrderingFilter(
        fields=(
            ('updated_at', 'updated_at'),  # field value, url param value
        ),
    )
```

You can read more about this here:
https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ref/filters.html?highlight=OrderingFilter#orderingfilter

> I'm thinking of add watch_count field in Product model and ordering
> for that field. But is that a good way to get what I need?

It depends. Solution above will work well for most cases, but for very large datasets it is possible that you will encounter some performance issues. For huge amounts of data, solution provided by yourself will be better. It is also very possible that the incoming django release (3.2) will help with fixing performance issues by enabling creation of functional indexes: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/releases/3.2/#functional-indexes